# Error 233 sql server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo solucionar este problema : ya intente desde administrador de servidores

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La base de datos está en la misma máquina que el SSMS?

Comment: Si en la misma maquina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una opción es que la configuración de conexión esté incorrecta:

1. En el menú inicio, busque el grupo MS SQL Server.
2. Abra `SQL Server Configuration Manager` >> `SQL Server Network Configuration`.
3. Elija la opción `TCP/IP` y habilítela con clic derecho (seleccione `Enable`).

Otra opción es que no esté habilitado el Shared Memory Protocol, que es requerido por MS SQL:

1. Vaya a Inicio → Todos los Programas → MS SQL Server → Configuration Tools → SQL Server Configuration Manager.
2. Seleccione `SQL Server Network Configuration`.
3. En la ventana que se muestra, haga clic derecho en la opción `Shared Memory` → seleccione `Enable`.

Otra opción es que haya líos en la configuración de la cuenta que intenta iniciar sesión:

1. Abra SQL Server Management studio e inicie sesión con "Windows Authentication"
2. Expanda el directorio `Security`del árbol
3. Expanda el directorio `logins`
4. Click derecho en la cuenta que no se conecta, seleccione `Propiedades`.
5. Solución - Asegúrese que hay una base de datos asignada en el campo "Default Database".